# Вопрос про ajax и jq

Tags: jquery, ajax

Добрый вечер!

Есть функция:

```
function sendRequest(_text)
    {
    $.ajax({ type: "POST", 
    url: "some.php", 
    data: _text, 
    success: blabla(),
    error: alert (_text)
    });
    }
```

Если, скажем 10 раз вызвать последовательно данную функцию, а на 8 итерации будет неудачное выполнение скрипта some.php, мне вывалится окошко с текстом 8 запроса или может с другим вывалиться?

Comment: а) если последовательно - то именно от этого запроса всё и прилетит б) можно же это самому протестировать, разве нет?

Comment: А если паралелльно? Уже ответы прилетают, но не могу понять соответсвует ли одно другому

Comment: `б) можно же это самому протестировать, разве нет?` .....ставишь чтоб на определенные данные (data) возвращало ошибку, запускаешь цикл, в котором в какой-то момент отдаешь данные, вызывающие ошибку и смотришь